# trigger input as datepicker in a table cell in modal window

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a table in my modal window and I add data to it using jquery ajax call,
when adding rows to table I also add an edit button to each row, so when the user clicks on the button, table cells on the specific row change to input so user can edit them,two of the inputs must be datepickers.
But when I trigger the datepickers using

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
})
```

it doesn't work at all, I also searched the web and came across some solutions like changing the input css to position:relative or z-index:99999 and ...
but none of them worked.
Your help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: update: I also trigger the datepicker immediately after appending the inputs to cells not before the inputs are appended

Comment: Add a code snippet to show what you have tried ?